# Recording on the server

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, javasound

I am developing a web application.  It is school software. In our application we have a functionality that should allow students to record their voice by reading the passage on the web page. It is a test. And also we simultaneously we need to display a count down timer on the page. And we used Java code to record the sound and JavaScript for count down timer.

Our Code:

```
public void start(String filePath) {
    try {

        File wavFile = new File(filePath);
     //   AudioFormat format = getAudioFormat();
        AudioFormat audioFormat = new AudioFormat(
                AudioFormat.Encoding.PCM_SIGNED,
                44100.0F, 16, 2, 4, 44100.0F, false);
        DataLine.Info info = new DataLine.Info(TargetDataLine.class, audioFormat);
        if (!AudioSystem.isLineSupported(info)) {
            System.out.println("Line not Supported");
        }
        line = (TargetDataLine) AudioSystem.getLine(info);
        line.open(audioFormat);
        line.start();   // start capturing
        AudioInputStream ais = new AudioInputStream(line);
        System.out.println("Start recording...");
        // start recording
        AudioSystem.write(ais, fileType, wavFile);

    } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
        System.out.println("Line not supported");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The problem is that the functionality is working locally on my machine but not working on the server (Our project website). I am getting a error that

```
No line matching interface TargetDataLine supporting format PCM_SIGNED 44100.0 Hz, 
  16 bit, stereo, 4 bytes/frame, little-endian is supported.
```

I am trying to resolve this issue but no solution.

Comment: Do you want to record the sound from the server room? Your record code has to be executed by the client not by the server, i.e. with an applet

Comment: I want to record the sound on the client machine and save it on the server

Comment: it was a joke, of course I've guessed that you want to record the client :) But  the AudioSystem represents a **local** hardware device, so if you start a record from an app hosted on the server,it will try to open the soundcard of the **server**, which is absent in your case and cause the error.

Comment: Ok. I got it. Would you please give us any solutions like any link for recording sound on the client machine through an applet or javascript?

Comment: Hi sir, please give me any solution for this problem

Comment: you can loot at my answer

Comment: I came to know that applets  does not support sound recording by default .-----"The main disadvantage of the browser embedded model is that currently the Java applets do not support voice recording. This is mostly because of security reasons. For security reasons, the applet can not run a program located in a local machine, or control a hardware device such as the sound card."

Answer (score 1):

> ..not working on the server

I would be surprised if the server had speakers & the server operators are probably glad it doesn't.  You need something that is **client-side** (e.g. an [applet](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/applet/info) or [JWS](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) app.) to play the sound!

Answer (score 0):

Develop and Applet that will capture the audio on the client and upload it to the server.
See the official [applet documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html).

Server side you can use your framework if you are using one to handle the file reception, or use [commons-fileupload](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/).

Client side, in your applet you can use [HTTPClient](https://hc.apache.org/) to do the stuff.

I will not being more precise as we are not here to develop your project but with these documentation you will get a lot of information to start.